# Null data on resumed activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activities A, B, C, D. In A activity I have list with some data. I called them A->B->C->D and when I clicked confirm button on D activity I must go to A. I use this code for this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(D.this,A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And when Activity A called, my List is null. I try to use onSavedInstanceState, but its also null.
How I can do this?

Comment: Try to use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the A `Activity` is recreating. You can do it from different ways:

- Call `finish()` method on `Activity` s D -> C -> B , and then `Activity` A pop up.
- Pass the list from `Activity` A to B -> C -> D, and then, pass again to the `Activity` A.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
**Solution 1.**
    Intent intent = new Intent(D.this,A.class);      
    startActivity(intent);
    finishAffinity();
Here "finishAffinity" will close all the activity and will create activity A.

**Solution 2.**
Intent intent = new Intent(D.this,A.class);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("reloadHome", true);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

Check value on A activity to override "onNewIntent"
If you will pass any value from activity D to A you can get that data into "onNewIntent" method. in this scenario.

@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
```